# Loading segmentation data with tf.data as Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I want to load and augment a custom dataset for segmentation. For segmentation, I prepared a `npz` file containing four subsets:

```py
with np.load(PATH) as data:
    train_x = data['x_train']
    valid_x = data['x_valid']
    train_y = data['y_train']
    valid_y = data['y_valid']
```

Train / valid have their corresponding meanings and x / y stand for the input image (x) and the segmentation mask (y). In training, my model will take the input x and the loss will be calculated on the model output relative to y.

My question now is how to go ahead to get a `tf.data` Dataset that I can iterate over in training. I have tried the following:

```py
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_x, train_y))

>>> train_dataset
<TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((520, 696), (520, 696)), types: (tf.uint16, tf.uint8)>

def load(data_group):
    image, mask = data_group
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    mask = tf.cast(mask, tf.float32)
    return image, mask

def normalize(image):
    return (image / 65535/2) - 1

def load_image_train(data_group):
    image, mask = load(data_group)
    image = normalize(image)
    # Perform augmentation (not shown)
    return image, mask

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(load_image_train, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

This, however, fails while trying to map the `load_image_train` train function returning an error  `tf__load_image_train() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. In general this approach feels slightly clunky and would love to know alternatives / possibilities to improve this data import.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In `load_image_train(data_group)` ,try taking 2 arguments as `def load_image_train(image,mask)` and change same for the other function

Comment: what seem to be problem?

Comment: Ah, I see. I ran it multiple times. Notebooks have their downsides. I think that solved my problem then. Just curious – is this the standard way to do it in the first place or are there  more elegant solutions?

Comment: try to change the sequence apply `map` after `batch` checkout [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data),and alos there tensorflow tutorial on youtube on tf dataset that you should checkouty

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVEOCfBy9uY. I assume. If you want to add a short answer mentioning that map automatically unzips the dataset I can upvote it.

Comment: yes that is the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write this way:

```
def load_image_train(image,mask):

  image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
  mask = tf.cast(mask, tf.float32)
  image = normalize(image)

  return image, mask
```

The `tf.data.Dataset` will return the pair of tensors in your case.

Also check out the [Tensorflow Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data)